# Errors on GOCD server startup with auhorization plugins

Tags: docker, go-cd

I'm gettting the follow errors on gocd-server docker startup:

```
[2017-12-05 14:46:36,252 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginInfoBuilder:55 - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin cd.go.authentication.ldap. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?
2017-12-05 14:46:36,269  WARN \[Thread-75\] p.c.g.a.l.c.g.a.l.LdapPlugin:67 \[plugin-cd.go.authentication.ldap\] - Request go.plugin-settings.get-configuration is not supported by plugin.
2017-12-05 14:46:36,270 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginSettingsMetadataLoader:75 - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin cd.go.authentication.ldap. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?
2017-12-05 14:46:37,689 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginSettingsMetadataLoader:75 - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin yum. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?
2017-12-05 14:46:37,792 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginInfoBuilder:55 - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin yum. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?
2017-12-05 14:46:37,954  INFO \[Thread-75\] p.c.g.a.p.c.g.a.p.PasswordFilePlugin:57 \[plugin-cd.go.authentication.passwordfile\] - Loading plugin cd.go.authentication.passwordfile version 1.0.1-48
2017-12-05 14:46:38,047  WARN \[Thread-75\] p.c.g.a.p.c.g.a.p.PasswordFilePlugin:67 \[plugin-cd.go.authentication.passwordfile\] - Request go.plugin-settings.get-view is not supported by plugin.
2017-12-05 14:46:38,048 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginInfoBuilder:55 - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin cd.go.authentication.passwordfile. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?
2017-12-05 14:46:38,055  WARN \[Thread-75\] p.c.g.a.p.c.g.a.p.PasswordFilePlugin:67 \[plugin-cd.go.authentication.passwordfile\] - Request go.plugin-settings.get-configuration is not supported by plugin.
2017-12-05 14:46:38,056 ERROR \[Thread-75\] PluginSettingsMetadataLoader:75 
    - Failed to fetch Plugin Settings metadata for plugin cd.go.authentication.passwordfile. Maybe the plugin does not implement plugin settings and view?][1]
```

After bad startup, I tried access /go/admin/security/auth_configs but showed me the message:

There was a problem fetching the auth configs
Refresh this page in some time, and if the problem persists, check the server logs.

The run has been executed on 4 last versions of gocd-server and the error occurred on all of them

Answer (score 0):

I have tried GoCD 17.12.0 on CentOS 7.x and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS docker base image with GoCD 17.12.0 and it works fine.

If you have not, build it from source. Are you using CentOS or Ubuntu as your base OS running this? I'm wondering if this is a bug.